# JqGrid Advanced Search - Save search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am creating a website and have a jqGrid on my page. I am using the advanced search feature by adding a custom button to my navgrid (pager) that calls the jqGrid 'searchGrid' function.

```
$('#My_Grid_Id').jqGrid(settingsObject)
.navGrid('My_Grid_Id_toolbar1',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,refresh:false,search:false})
 .navButtonAdd('My_Grid_Id_toolbar1', 
 { 
    caption: 'Search', 
    buttonicon: 'ui-icon-search', 
    title: 'Search', 
    onClickButton: function() { 
        $(gridSelector).jqGrid ('searchGrid', {
            caption: 'Search',
            multipleSearch:true, 
            overlay: false,
            multipleGroup:true,
            recreateFilter: true
         });
     } 
});
```

I would like to be able to save the search settings when the user leaves the page so I can reload them when the user returns. I almost have a working solution, but after I have saved and reloaded the search settings, the 'Reset' button on the search dialog window does not work as expected. The search setting do seem to be reset in the background but the window does not refresh and the grid still shows the old results.

To explain a bit more. I catch the window unload event and store the search settings by sending the potdata.filters parameter to the server with an ajax call. I then store the data in a cookie which I can load later.

```
$(window).unload( function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: saveUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        data: { 
            searchSettings: $('#My_Grid_Id').getGridParam('postData').filters       
        }
    });
});
```

When I reload the grid I check if my cookie has a value then insert the saved filters back into the grid in the constructor.

```
postData: { 
    filters: mySavedSearchSettings                  
},
```

At this point the grid works well, the search has been saved and the results show as expected. When I open the search window dialog the search options appear as expected. But when I click the 'Reset' button the window does not update properly and neither do the grid results. I have attempted to add an onclick event to the reset button to manually reset the search but nothing seems to happen.

```
afterShowSearch: function() {
    $('.fm-button-icon-left').click(function(){
        $('#My_Grid_Id').jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
}
```

Can anyone offer any help? I think I am close, I just need to reset the search window somehow then reload the grid.

Comment: does the reset button reset the settings?

Comment: I'm a little wary of an async call that happens on unload.  Are you sure that the settings are always saved to the cookie?  If you don't get any traction with your approach to the Reset button, I might suggest a radical idea: save the settings every time they change, not just on unload.

Comment: Saving the settings does not seem to be a problem. The cookie is always created properly and the grid always loads with the saved search. When I click the reset button, it appears as though nothing has happened. But if I then leave the page and return the search has been reset. So it is as though the postData filters is cleared but the search window and grid are not actually refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be two things.

Firstly, the grid was not reloading the correct data as I did not correctly handle the server side code. I have recently started using php and I had a bug where the code did not correctly identify that the filter post data was null/empty.

Secondly, I was able to reset the search window dialog by calling the 'searchGrid' function to open it again. So after the search is shown I add an on click event to the reset button as follows:-

```
$(gridSelector).navButtonAdd(gridSelector + '_toolbar1', 
    { 
        caption: 'Search', 
        buttonicon: 'ui-icon-search', 
        title: 'Search', 
        onClickButton: function() { OpenAdvancedSearchDialog(gridSelector); } 
    });
}

function OpenAdvancedSearchDialog(gridSelector) {
    $(gridSelector).jqGrid ('searchGrid', {
        caption: 'Search',
        multipleSearch:true, 
        overlay: false,
        multipleGroup:true,
        recreateFilter: true,
        afterShowSearch: function() {
            $('.fm-button-icon-left').click(function(){
                OpenAdvancedSearchDialog(gridSelector);
            });
       }
    });
}
```